# i got this error with installing laravel. how to fix this?

Tags: php, laravel

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   Your configuration does not
>   allow connections to http://packagist.org/packages.json. See
>   https://getcomposer.org/do   c/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

Comment: And is really problem of laravel? I guess your composer have bad configuration. Tried to reinstall it?

Comment: Please reinstall composer.

Comment: `https` i suppose

Comment: i reinstalled the composer.but still get this error

Comment: Check you can access that file in browser using both https and http. If https fails, thats your problem. Could be anything depending on your local setup really.

Comment: thank u. fixed it. :D